# Nginx read headers of django response from proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Have been reading quite a few stackoverflows, tried `$upstream_http_<name>` and `$sent_http_<name>` both got nothing, hence I am starting a new question:

```
    location = /novnc-auth {
        internal;
        # calls the django view below
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/proxmox/novnc-connection-lookup/$cookie_novnc/;
        # set $pve $upstream_http_pve;
        # set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
    }

    location = /novnc/ {
        auth_request /novnc-auth;
        proxy_set_header Cookie 'PVEAuthCookie=$upstream_http_pve';
        proxy_pass https://$upstream_http_vmhhost/$is_args$args;

    }
```

django view

```py
   def view(self, ...):
        data = json.loads(data_string)
        resp = HttpResponse(data_string)
        resp['Pve'] = data['pve']
        resp['Vmhhost'] = data['host']
        return resp
```

So basically I want to get the value of `Pve` and `Vmhhost` set by django view inside nginx `/novnc/` block, currently I am getting `no host in upstream` which means the upstream_http_vmhhost is empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an [`auth_request_set`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request_set) directive in your `location = /novnc-auth { ... }` to save upstream HTTP header values. You will also need a [`reslover`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive for that configuration.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks for the `auth_request_set` suggestion, I am getting somewhere, can you please elaborate a bit on the `resolver` directive? Why do I need that?

Comment: A short answer - because you define an upstream hostname via variable in a `proxy_pass` directive. For a long answer you can read [this](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) article.